# getting "KeyError" while implementing Z-score on a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, normalization

I have been trying to implement z-score normalization to all of the numeric values present in combined_data with the following code:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore

# Calculate the zscores and drop zscores into new column
combined_data['zscore'] = zscore(combined_data['zscore'])
```

Here, `combined_data` is the combination of training and testing datasets as a dataframe and passed through one-hot encoding.

I am seeing the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:2646, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645 try:
-> 2646     return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647 except KeyError:

File pandas/_libs/index.pyx:111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/index.pyx:138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'zscore'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [29], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Calculate the zscores and drop zscores into new column
----> 2 combined_data['zscore'] = zscore(combined_data['zscore'])

File ~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:2800, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   2798 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801 if is_integer(indexer):
   2802     indexer = [indexer]

File ~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:2648, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646         return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647     except KeyError:
-> 2648         return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649 indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650 if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

File pandas/_libs/index.pyx:111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/index.pyx:138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'zscore'
```

The dataset `combined_data` contains *257673 rows* & *198 columns*

Here is the sample data of `combined_data`

```
id  dur spkts   dpkts   sbytes  dbytes  rate    sttl    dttl    sload   ... state_CLO   state_CON   state_ECO   state_FIN   state_INT   state_PAR   state_REQ   state_RST   state_URN   state_no
60662   60663   1.193334    10  10  608 646 15.921779   254 252 3673.740967 ... 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

[image of sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXJF6.png)

I am new to such error. What am I doing wrong?

[UPDATE: The code was trying to create a separate column with with zscore which is not possible to do so as it is mentioned below]

Comment: I have included sample data in the question @ewong. I wasn't sure how to include the sample data properly since simply copying the data on the jupyter notebook and pasting it here does not work, due to which i have included a image of the sample data. Please do let me know if you know how to include the sample data properly here.

Comment: Column `combined_data['zscore']` does not exist. Did you want to apply the function to another column?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use OCR if necessary. Type if necessary. [No images of text.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. Show what you are able to do. Research before considering asking & reflect research in a question. [ask] [Help]

Comment: ? Query and/or update to get smaller input while still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply the function `zscore` to the whole dataframe, not to a non-existent column:

```
result = zscore(combined_data)
```

The result is a numpy array. You cannot make it a column of the original dataframe. But you can create another DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(result, columns=combined_data.columns, index=combined_data.index)
```

Comment: I see. doing this converts my data-frame to array which I don't want. I want each cell to get z-score'ed (excluding the column name). I am planning to run it through a 'for' loop, but not sure exactly how to do it since I am new to this.

Comment: You can easily convert it back to a dataframe. See the update.

Comment: Unfortunately now I am seeing an error `AttributeError: ‘numpy.ndarray’ object has no attribute ‘columns’` While I am trying to convert the array to dataframe

Comment: You must have redefined some if your variables. Is `combined_data` STILL a dataframe?

Comment: Yes, it is still a dataframe.

Comment: So what I did was create a function “z_score” and passed the combined_data through it. I am getting the output in array just like before but when I am trying to convert the array to dataframe, getting the AttributeError.