# getting "KeyError" while implementing Z-score on a dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, normalization

I have been trying to implement z-score normalization to all of the numeric values present in combined_data with the following code:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore

# Calculate the zscores and drop zscores into new column
combined_data['zscore'] = zscore(combined_data['zscore'])
```

Here, `combined_data` is the combination of training and testing datasets as a dataframe and passed through one-hot encoding.

I am seeing the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:2646, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645 try:
-> 2646     return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647 except KeyError:

File pandas/_libs/index.pyx:111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/index.pyx:138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'zscore'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [29], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Calculate the zscores and drop zscores into new column
----> 2 combined_data['zscore'] = zscore(combined_data['zscore'])

File ~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:2800, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   2798 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801 if is_integer(indexer):
   2802     indexer = [indexer]

File ~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:2648, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646         return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647     except KeyError:
-> 2648         return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649 indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650 if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

File pandas/_libs/index.pyx:111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/index.pyx:138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'zscore'
```

The dataset `combined_data` contains *257673 rows* & *198 columns*

Here is the sample data of `combined_data`

```
id  dur spkts   dpkts   sbytes  dbytes  rate    sttl    dttl    sload   ... state_CLO   state_CON   state_ECO   state_FIN   state_INT   state_PAR   state_REQ   state_RST   state_URN   state_no
60662   60663   1.193334    10  10  608 646 15.921779   254 252 3673.740967 ... 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

[image of sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXJF6.png)

I am new to such error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not [delete & repost questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71930134/3404097). (Especially to subvert closure or other account restrictions--not the case here.) Instead, edit per feedback. (Don't make us repeat our feedback.) Don't do anything with another account that you can't do with 1. Poorly received questions (score <=0) count towards voting limits even when deleted.  [Help] [tag:database-normalization] is a specific kind or normalization that rearranges table designs. It is not for normalization of data that happens to be in a DB. That is why I removed it on the last version.